# Why does OpenMP not parallelize vtk IntersectWithLine code

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp, vtk

I have trouble understanding why a **for-loop**, parallelized with OpenMP, does not use all `n_threads` threads (=2x #cores) if a Vtk code is executed inside the loop. Specifically I want to intersect lines / rays with a mesh. I followed [this tutorial](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/DataStructures/OBBTreeIntersectWithLine)  by

1. building an OBB tree from the mesh
2. intersecting all required lines with the mesh

Because I wanted to parallelize it, I create `n_threads` trees, such that each thread could work with it's own instance of a tree:

```cpp
// Pre-allocate the array
int n_threads = omp_get_max_threads();
trees = std::vector<vtkSmartPointer<vtkOBBTree>>((unsigned int) n_threads);

// Build n_threads OBB trees
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(n_threads)
for (int t = 0; t < n_threads; ++t)
{
    trees[t] = vtkSmartPointer<vtkOBBTree>::New();
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData> mesh_clone = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData>::New();
    #pragma omp critical (build_mesh_tree)
    {
        mesh_clone->DeepCopy(mesh);
    }
    trees[t]->SetDataSet(mesh_clone);
    trees[t]->BuildLocator();
}
```

Then I loop over all points to calculate the intersection between `origin` and each point in `points`

```cpp
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(n_threads)
for (unsigned long i = 0; i < n_points; ++i)
{
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints> intersection_points = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints>::New();
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkIdList> cell_ids = vtkSmartPointer<vtkIdList>::New();

    int this_thread = omp_get_thread_num();
    int code = trees[this_thread]->IntersectWithLine(
            origin.data(),       // pointer to the raw data
            points.at(i).data(), // buffer of a Eigen matrix
            intersection_points,
            cell_ids);

    // Do something with intersection_points and cell_ids
}
```

OpenMP has shown to work as expected for simple C++ code. However when wrapped around Vtk calls, it does not achieve its purpose. I suppose this is due to the fact that Vtk already offers a [parallelization framework](http://www.vtk.org/parallel-processing/) ([ref. to the guide](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/images/3/3b/VTK_SMP_Guide.pdf)).

If that is the case, can you explain, why OpenMP fails to run the vtk-related code in parallel? If not, what could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

How exactly does it fail? Have you tried just e.g. printing the thread number to see if n_threads is spawned? If you are "just" getting wrong results in the `intersection_points` and `cell_ids`, that is because those arrays are reset by each thread whenever they enter the `IntersectWithLine` function (you can look at the implementation [here](https://github.com/Kitware/VTK/blob/master/Filters/General/vtkOBBTree.cxx), lines 800-808).

To solve this, the easiest solution that comes to mind is have each thread have it's own list and then concatenate them in a critical section, but faster will probably be pre-allocating array of those list for each thread and then reading the results from it, e.g.:

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints> *inter_points = new vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints> [n_threads];
vtkSmartPointer<vtkIdList> *inter_cells = new vtkSmartPointer<vtkIdList> [n_threads];
for (unsigned long i = 0; i < n_threads; ++i)
{
    inter_points[i] = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints>::New();
    inter_cells[i] = vtkSmartPointer<vtkIdList>::New();
}

#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(n_threads)
for (unsigned long i = 0; i < n_points; ++i)
{
    int this_thread = omp_get_thread_num();
    int code = trees[this_thread]->IntersectWithLine(
            origin.data(), // pointer to the raw data
            points.at(i).data(), // buffer of a Eigen matrix
            inter_points[this_thread],
            inter_cells[this_thread);
}

// now concatenate the results to one array if necessarry
```

*(didn't compile, might have syntax bugs, just plain C, so not the safest way...)*

Comment: Thanks for this response! I updated my question above. Of course it does not make sense to overwrite (potentially thread unsafe) the contents of `intersection_points` and `intersection_cells`. I moved this code inside the loop now.
Also I was unspecific about how OpenMP _fails_. The calculations are correct. It just simply does not execute the vtk part of the code on all threads simultaneuosly. I can confirm though that `n_threads` are spawned. It just seems that the thread calling a vtk function first, locks the others.